# Yazeed44 MultiImagePicker not working

Tags: android, android-image

I was trying to implement the MultiImagePicker from Yazeed44 (https://github.com/yazeed44/MultiImagePicker).
The problem I have is, when I open the image selector:

```
 new Picker.Builder(getActivity(), new MyPickListener(), R.style.MIP_theme)
            .build()
            .startActivity();
```

The view remains empty where it should be displaying the photo albums to select from. See the screenshot:

[image]

What am I missing in order to get this to work?
I'm testing with a Google Nexus 6P with Android 6.0.1. minSdkVersion 19, targetSdkVersion 23. And I'm Gradle importing: net.yazeed44.imagepicker:imagepicker:1.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Try to set targetSdkVersion to 22, the problem occurs because in android 6 you need to request for permissions at run-time. If you have configured targetSdkVersion to 23 in your project, your app needs to support Runtime Permission, but if you doesn't have your code prepared to manage this, you neeed to change targetSdkVersion to 22, in this way you are going to get de old permission behavior.

> "Warning: Right now when you create a new project in Android Studio.
>   targetSdkVersion will be automatically set to the latest version, 23.
>   If you are not ready to make your application fully support the
>   Runtime Permission, I suggest you to step down the targetSdkVersion to
>   22 first."

https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en

Comment: I'm using targetSdkVersion 23 in my app and I've already changed the code accordingly for runtime permission. so this can't be the problem. I actually changed to another library which works like a charm.

Comment: I had the same problem some weeks ago, and I resolve it with that tip.